# Where are the Azure Functions Local Host Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

when a version 2 azure function starts locally where the settings below, specifically the MaxBatchSize. I've tried putting the new values in extensions in the host.json but they are just ignored.

```
EventHubOptions
{
"BatchCheckpointFrequency": 1,
"EventProcessorOptions": {
  "EnableReceiverRuntimeMetric": false,
  "InvokeProcessorAfterReceiveTimeout": false,
  "MaxBatchSize": 10,
  "PrefetchCount": 300,
  "ReceiveTimeout": "00:01:00"
  }
}
```

cheers

Johnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your json is wrong

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#host-json

It should look like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "eventHubs": {
            "batchCheckpointFrequency": 1,
            "eventProcessorOptions": {
                "maxBatchSize": 10,
                "prefetchCount": 300,
                "receiveTimeout": "00:01:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yep thats got it. I've tried all sorts of config and I thought i tried that! obviously
not! cheers